# How to find the difference of aggregate sum of a column from different groups in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

I need to find the difference of amounts from 2 different groups for every user.
[image]
Explanation:
For User 1, the sum of amounts of type A is 10+50 = 60 and type B is 10, so the difference of sums of type A and B is 60 - 10 = 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select usr,
    sum(case when type = 'A' then amount else -amount end) as amount
from mytable 
where type in ('A', 'B')
group by usr
```

Note: `user` is a language keyword, I used `usr` instead.

Comment: Well, so is TYPE